# How can I retrieve files which are deleted from command line using rm -rf in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

How can I retrieve files which are  accidentally deleted from command line using rm -rf in unix?

Comment: You cannot. You need to invest in doing backups!

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/769357/recovering-from-a-rm-rf

Comment: While probably off-topic, all may not be lost according to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files) answer. It might require some stitching together, with inodes, etc., but it might be enough to retrieve something.

Comment: It depends on what filesystem you use, how much time has passed since `rm`, was filesystem remounted read-only after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do anything to change what happened but the best resolution out of this would be to learn from your "mistakes".
What i have to propose is something a bit smart actually, because sometimes we get too cocky when deleting files i added a verification whenever i delete something. So if you would open your << .profile >> (which should be located in your home directory) either with vi or gedit or whatever you like, just add this line of code:

```
alias rm="/bin/rm -i"
```

and every time you will try to delete something the terminal will ask you:

```
rm: remove file_name (yes/no)?
```

thats a way of trying to 'save' your files when deleting them....
if you use this, you just use rm as you used to, nothing changes on that one..
Hope you liked it :)

Comment: Having the alias `alias rm="/bin/rm -i"` is a terrible idea. People get use to it - then log in as another user - then guess what happens?

Comment: i see the hate comming from personal experience..... but really, why would they log in as another user? and even if they have more than one accounts just add this on every .profile of their accounts, end of story... anyways, this is used just to recheck you shouldnt count on that always... point is to be carefull what you delete on the first point not when the alias is warning you about it.... this is just used for precaution....

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos: eg. because thay need to run sth as root. Besides, they may log in to another machine, log in to a fresh install without aliases installed etc.

Comment: still guys, its like 40 seconds of your time to add this alias and you will pray to god for adding it when it would help avoid a mistake by deleting it.... p.s if you are connected to a server and using sun oracle for example, then from whichever machine you log in, its gonna be stilll the files being read, so same .profile. anyways i think this is a great idea, saved my as.s many times, hope it does for this guy as well....

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos - Try being a systems administrator with multiple machines. Multiple accounts on each machine running a different service. Better not to reply on the `-i` bit. People get into the mindset `rm -fr` - I can select what ones to delete. Bang - it is tears and trying to find the backup

Comment: anywaysssssss... i suppose that @Ratha is not a system administrator rather than a simple user, so he could find this quite usefull.....

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos Pathetic developer, deleted my project..and not 'he'. Have a nice profile pic :)

Comment: @Ratha i am sorry for your loss :p , i am sure the guy didnt want to delete your project.... and sorry for the 'he' as well, but from the work server i am working on all pictures are blocked so i couldnt have known :)